# current working directory in PATH variable: Does this make sense?

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables, pwd

I'm having an old Linux enviroment here which I currently start to move to a new Linux Server.

In the old enviroment, I found inside `~/.profile` that the current working directory is being exported to `PATH`:

`export PATH=$PATH:.`

What might be the reason that the old administrator has put this inside `~/.profile`? Because this only safes two characters when trying to execute a program inside the current working directory, doesn't it? (for example: `./foobar` vs. `foobar`)

Comment: As you say, this is useful to run programs that are stored in the home dir. You indeed save just two cars: from `myprogram` to `./myprogram` if you are in the home dir or `myprogram` instead of `~/myprogram` if you are not. It sounds more dangerous than useful.

Comment: Ok, glad, that I'm not the only one who thinks that this might be rather dangerous than useful.

Comment: You can "save" one more character: `export PATH=$PATH:` (no dot needed).